# Stateless wicket page still having page version URL parameter appended - how to debug?

Tags: parameters, wicket, stateless

I am trying to make a page of my project completely stateless (more pages to come) and by doing get rid of the page version number, e.g. `/mypage/?0`

The page sets `statelessHint` to true, I have also verified in `onBeforeRender` that `isStateless` returns true.
I also use the `@StatelessComponent` annotation to make sure the page and its child components are really, really stateless.

So, it seems that everything is stateless, however the version parameter is still appended to the URL

I cannot attach the code, since it is a huge construct with many components and a lot of inheritance involved. Of course, I do not expect anyone to tell me where there problems is, but rather hope for some to give me a hint when to place a breakpoint in Wicket's sources to find out what is going wrong. E.g. can anybody tell me which Wicket class is responsible for deciding whether or not to append the version parameter?

Thanks in advance,
Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviosuly, `@StatelessComponent` is not always reliable down into all child components :(

You can debug this by setting the log level for `org.apache.wicket.Page` to `DEBUG`, which adds loads of lines to your console output. Grep for "is not stateless because" to find messages about rendered components that are stateful.

In my case, it was an `Image`, whose `getStatelessHint()` method returned `false` (no idea why).

Comment: Because you have used an Image backed up by IResource. To be able to find the IResource Wicket needs to find the image, thus the page is stateful. Back it up by ResourceReference or plain url and it will be stateless.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now that I look at it, I actually think that it should rather inherit WebComponent directly anyway, since the component does not even use the resource.

Answer (score 5):

To verify that pages are stateless you have to call `Page#isPageStateless` instead of `Page#isStateless`.

For the sake of completeness I'll also mention that the `@StatelessComponent` itself does nothing but you have to install the `StatelessChecker` with

```
getComponentPreOnBeforeRenderListeners().add(new StatelessChecker());
```

in `Application#init`. I think it works pretty well and it should find any stateful components.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the existence of `Page#isPageStateless`, good to know. However, I have just reproduced the case I had before, and it returned `true` as well. :( So I'd still need to turn on debugging for `org.apache.wicket.Page` to find out.